How to see my Android partitions via Linux machine terminal?
When I connect my Android device via USB into a Linux machine (be it Debian, Ubuntu, Arch, etc.) I am unable to find any trace of the device or partitions using cmds fdisk -l, lsblk, etc.
This is apparently due to the Android device not being treated like regular USB storage and being accessed through MTP.
How can I view my Android partition tables etc? Ideally without downloading adb, using basic Linux pre-installed packages.

Possible dupe: Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?. Possibly related: How to enable USB mass storage feature on newer Android phones

Indeed, an Android device is not mounted as regular storage. If it were, connecting more than one Android device at a time would become complicated, with potential for confusion over which partition belonged to which device.
You do need adb to obtain this kind of access to an Android device. Many Linux distributions have their own builds of adb available for installation through their respective package managers. Is that more acceptable than downloading from  developer.android.com?

After installing adb and android-tools-adb, after calling adb start-server followed by adb devices, I cannot see any device in the list, I also approved the connection in my android device. What do you suspect maybe the problem

Try this command sequence adb kill-server, then sudo adb start-server, then adb devices.
